# jQuery UI Tabs - conflict between cookie & select just added tab?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies

I am using [jquery.cookies](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/) to keep a tab selected after refresh.

I would also like that as soon as a new tab is created, it is selected.

Using jQuery UI instructions I currently have:

```
    var cookieName = 'stickyTab';

    $(".tabs").tabs({
        fx: {
            opacity: 'toggle',
            duration: 'fast'
        },
        selected: ( $.cookies.get( cookieName ) || 0 ),
                    select: function( e, ui )
                {
                $.cookies.set( cookieName, ui.index );
                }
    });

    var $tabs = $('.tabs').tabs({
    add: function(event, ui) {
        $tabs.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work -- when I create a new tab, the one that was previously open remains selected (maybe because the cookie is overriding the `select` function?

My tabs are created via PHP POST and data is retrieved from DB and looped to create `LI` and `DIV` elements. (ie, my tabs are ***not*** created directly from JS).

Anyone have suggestions to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Added `$tabs.tabs('select', '#' + ui.panel.id);` to [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation). And it behaved as [intended](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/WrGYJ/). Is this all the relevant code ?

Comment: @khez - i think the difference between your fiddle and my situation is that I am not adding the tab via JS - my new tabs are created server side from a POST with new data that is then collected from the DB and then runs thru a loop to form the `lis` and `divs`

Comment: Then considering tagging your question with PHP/ASP or at least mentioning that in your post. How are you adding tabs ?

Comment: sorry, fixed the OP - i add the tabs by providing a PHP form that saves data to DB - then a query generates an array that populates the fields in tab(s) using a foreach loop

Comment: I'm still struggling to grasp your situation, are you building the new tabs via AJAX and just adding the response to the tabs? or are you refreshing the page when adding new tabs ?

Comment: thx for your patience khez - page is refreshed once the data is entered in the form - during refresh, my CI controller/model runs the query which returns the array to the view for looping

Comment: Then you're in luck! let's say you're adding 3 tabs, then you just need to update the `$_COOKIE['stickyTab']+=3;` in PHP before any data is sent to the browser :)

Comment: ok! I'll play around with this idea and post back - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your bug stems from the fact you're only updating your cookies via JavaScript, but are adding new tabs via PHP on page reloads. This results in new tabs being appended but not synced with your cookie.

Since the jQuery UI Tabs `selected` property is an index. And you're tabs are created via an array, a simple:

```
setcookie('stickyTab',count($array)-1);
// this will set the selected tab to the last appended tab
```

Take note you only need to run this statement when new tabs are appended. Otherwise you will overwrite the cookie set via JS.

If you have any more issues, be sure to comment and we'll try and fix.

Comment: Thanks @khez - in what line of my original JS code should I insert this -- should I remove line 8-12 and replace with `selected: set_cookie('stickyTab',count($array)-1);` -- or should I **add** this line somewhere else?

Comment: That's a PHP statement, add it in your PHP before headers are sent.

Comment: unfortunately i get a server error when i add that line at the top of my PHP (instead of `$array` i used my array's name)

Comment: man, I think i need to get some sleep :P -- I was using `set_cookie` instead of `setcookie` -- anyway, now it works but here's the situation - when I create a new tab, it goes straight to the new tab (good) -- but when i select another tab and refresh, it goes to the last tab

Comment: only do that statement when you add new tabs.

Comment: @khez - the array containing user records loops every time there is a page refresh and when a record is added - so i don't think there is a way of indicating when a new record was added, since the process of showing new+old records is the same as showing old records - can you think of a conditional that would only run the cookie statement when a new record was added?

Comment: well you can either use a cookie or a session var to remember the old total and if the new total changes, update the cookie